# How to change class name tag a with specific href?

Tags: jquery, html, href

Here my problem.

```
<a class="selected" href="#tab-general">General Setting</a>
<a href="#tab-setting1">Method 1</a>
```

This time, it's auto selected #tab-general. Now after click some button I want it auto select the #tab-setting1. I already try this thing but it didn't work:

```
var text='#tab-setting'+1;
$('.selected').attr('class','');
$('a[href$=text]').attr('class', 'selected');
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand the question. You just want to `toggle` the class of `selected` between the two...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Text is a variable. So change this

```
$('a[href$=text]').attr('class', 'selected'); //this selector does not read the value of variable `text`
```

to

```
$('a[href$='+text+']').attr('class', 'selected');
```

I would suggest you to do something similar to below.

Html:

```
<a class="link selected" href="#tab-general">General Setting</a>
<a class="link" href="#tab-setting1">Method 1</a>
```

Jquery:

```
$('.link').on("click",function(){
    $('.link').removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");
})
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c5f9c/)